# Intentions for sawm

Tags: sawm, ramadan

I had to fast 2 days kadaa' for ramadan, so I made them at the beginning of Shawal with the intention of fasting the 6 days of shawal plus the kadaa'. My question is: Is that accepted?

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear please? Were those 6 days Mustahab fasts?

Comment: Yes, they are mustahab days and have the ajr of fasting a year (based on what I heard from alot of people). So I made the two days kadaa' plus the intention of the 6 days of shawal.

Comment: Do you mean you fasted for 6 days shawal and 2 days kada? means that totaly 8 days. Or you fasted only 6 days with both intentions??

Comment: @RehanUllah I fasted 6 days, two of those days were double intentions.

Comment: As much as I know, it is permissible to be fasted (as Qaza) at the days which are counted as Mustahab days. Of course the significant point is that your intention ought to be for the Qaza fasting (with the hope of having that Mustahab fast thawab too). And Allah knows best.

Comment: Therefore, it can be accepted if your main intention was for the Qazaa fasts, afterwards you hoped that Allah will give you those thawabsas well. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean, you fasted for 6 days, with 2 first days with both intentions (kadaa' and shawal), I don't think it is okay to do that.

Kadaa' fast is a must, a compulsory, since it substitute ramadan fast, but shawal is not a mandatory. I guess it would be safe if you fast 2 days for kadaa' first, then continue with 6 days for shawal.

Comment: Where did you get this information from? An aswer can't be just one's own thought. It must have references!!!

Comment: @RehanUllah, Sometimes things are true but the one who is stating them may not come up with the references which I also agree that it is a necessity but not coming up with references do not make his point utterly useless and instead it only makes it weak. Right now I do not have any references either but I would just want you to know that "Nicky Irawan" is correct about what he has said and I agree with him. The reason I am typing this message is to help you by telling this answer is correct and you should quickly fast 8 days to get reward of 6 fasts of shawwal as well.

Comment: @Imran Do you think so? But I know that fasting 6 days with both intentions doesn't matter and sawab of both are achieved. And I think doing so is ok. Could you have a look here which proves that having both intentions are ok http://www.onislam.net/english/ask-the-scholar/acts-of-worship/fasting/170621-double-intention-in-shawwal-fasting-allowed.html And as he is trying to prove it as not ok therefore, I asked for reference with out which his answer becomes invalid.

Comment: @RehanUllah, In that column it is written "However, it is recommended that one makes up for the missed fasts separately from fasting the six days of Shawwal [so as to get extra reward]." I do not consider myself a scholar but all I can say is to try and play it safe by fasting 8 days rather than 6. Rest is your choice and thanks for the link!!!

Comment: @Imran Yeah it is written it is recommended but it is not written it is compulsory. And your point is also good to fast 8 instead of 6 but the asker has observed 6 fasts and time is over now and he might not be capable of fasting more. Therefore, we can't discourage him by saying No. Therefore I am trying to pacify him that he has fulfilled his duty!

Comment: @RehanUllah, How is the time over? He can still observe two fasts in shawwal. It is currently the month of shawwal and he can still observe fasts. As for his capability then if he has covered up compulsory fasts but not the shawwal fasts then at least he isn't getting any sins.